# Python lists - Copy list values in new list

Tags: python, list

This is what I am trying:

I have a text file with few lines of input in the format - `parameter value`

This text file is read line by line and parameters & values are taken into as list elements.

```
a = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    a.append((line.strip()).split(' '))
print a
```

Output:

```
[['parameter1': 'value1'], ['parameter2': 'value2'], ['parameter3': 'value3']]
```

I am now trying to move these values - value1, value2, value3, & so on - in to a new list.

I can't figure this out. copy function will copy the full list. Do I use loops to iterate through these values and append to new list? Is it possible to add these values directly to new list while reading from the text file..?

Comment: Please show us your **actual** output. The output in your question is not valid Python.

Comment: @MattDMo more like a `dict_list`

Comment: @MattDMo output was missing spaces only. Fixed.

Comment: @Sunshine: That isn't the problem.  Lists can't have colons.  Those should be commas.  If you run your code, you should be able to get what it prints.

Comment: My bad, I had used strip and split to clean off \n and make list values come in with a ':'. Thnx for pointing out. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a list comprehension:

```
new_a = [sub[1] for sub in a]
```

You could also do this:

```
import operator

new_a = list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), a))
```

An equivalent of that is to use a `lambda` function:

```
new_a = list(map(lambda x: x[1], a))
```

As mentioned in a comment, you could also do this:

```
new_a = [value for parameter, value in a]
```

That last will throw an error if any of the lists in `a` is not of length two.  That could be a good thing or a bad thing depending on what you want.

You could also just use your `for` loop only add just the second element:

```
a = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    a.append(line.split(' ')[1])
print a
```

I must confess, I didn't even notice that until I saw flaschbier's answer.

Comment: Or `[value for param, value in a]`

Comment: @tobias_k: That's true.  I added that.

Comment: what of `list(map(lambda x: x[1], a))`

Comment: @danidee: Sure, but using `operator.itemgetter(1)` removes the need of defining a lambda function, but I added it just for you :)

Comment: Worked smooth! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.append(line.split(' ')[1])
```

will append only the `value` from each line to another list `b` you have prepared before the loop.

The output of the program from the question will be

```
[['parameter1', 'value1'], ['parameter2', 'value2'], ['parameter3', 'value3']]
```

btw...